# Trying to Group Rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I thought my DISTINCT statement would help group by orders.customer_num, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I believe it has something to do with my expression in my SELECT statement. Really new to SQL.

```
SELECT DISTINCT orders.customer_num AS "Customer Number", 
       COUNT(orders.order_num) AS "Number of Orders",
       SUM(items.quantity) AS "Total Quantity", stock.unit_price AS "Unit Price",
       items.quantity * stock.unit_price AS "Total Price"
FROM orders,
     items,
     stock
WHERE orders.order_num = items.order_num
  AND items.stock_num = stock.stock_num
GROUP BY orders.customer_num, items.quantity, stock.unit_price
ORDER BY orders.customer_num;
```

Attached a pic showing what I am getting. 
[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZGmL.png)

Comment: can you please attach table descriptions. are you sure you want to group them with customer number alone?if thats the case, the result you are getting is correct since the resulting data shows that for each customer, many items has been purchased(if my assumptions is correct, that is one item for every unit price).

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.) Also, SELECT DISTINCT is rarely needed when GROUP BY.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: you may get rid of `distinct` here, useless. At most of sql you may prefer `group by` rather than `distinct`, because of performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Your `stock.unit_price` seems to be unique. Logically it selects `unit_price` per `item`. Either you need to discard the `stock` table and the related join conditions or sum it up

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to `group` by customer and calculate total for all columns? if i am right  you dont need to `group by` `items.quantity, stock.unit_price` columns and `distinct`, try this

```
SELECT orders.customer_num AS "Customer Number", 
       COUNT(orders.order_num) AS "Number of Orders", -- or SUM() depends on your logic
       SUM(items.quantity) AS "Total Quantity", 
       SUM(stock.unit_price) AS "Unit Price", 
       SUM(items.quantity * stock.unit_price) AS "Total Price"
 FROM  orders, items, stock
 WHERE orders.order_num = items.order_num
   AND items.stock_num = stock.stock_num
 GROUP BY orders.customer_num
 ORDER BY orders.customer_num;
```